# How to Scale target feature

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-scaling

How should I scale target feature? Should I use scaler as fit_transform on y_train, and just fit on y_test to avoid leaking data?

Comment: I guess you meant "just transform on y_test to avoid leaking data".

Answer (score 2):

You should fit your scaler only on train data, and then transform the test data with the fitted scaler. You should avoid fitting the scaler with the test data, since if you do that you would have a data leak.